# Testing event listener

Tags: c#, nunit, nsubstitute

In my code:

```
public class StudentPresenter
{
    IView myview;
    Repository myrepo;
    public StudentPresenter(IView vw, Data.Repository rep)
    {
        this.myview = vw;
        this.myrepo = rep;
        this.myview.ButonClick += myview_ButonClick;
    }

    public void myview_ButonClick()
    {
        var d = this.myrepo.GetById(int.Parse(myview.GivenId));
        this.myview.GetStudent(d);
    }
}
```

I want to test `GetStudent` method will call, So I tried

```
[Test]
public void ctor_whenviewbuttonclick_callsviewButtonClickevent()
{
    var mock = Substitute.For<IView>();
    var stub=Substitute.For<Repository>();
    Student st = new Student();
    stub.When(p => p.GetById(Arg.Any<int>())).Do(x => st=new Student());

    StudentPresenter sp = new StudentPresenter(mock, stub);

    mock.ButonClick += Raise.Event<Action>();

    mock.Received().GetStudent(st);      
}
```

But test broken: Says:

> *Application.UnitTests.Form1Tests.ctor_whenviewbuttonclick_callsviewButtonClickevent:
>   NSubstitute.Exceptions.ReceivedCallsException : Expected to receive a
>   call matching:    GetStudent(Student) Actually received no matching
>   calls.*

What I m doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is likely caused by `Repository.GetById()` not being `virtual`. The introduction on the [Creating a substitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/creating-a-substitute/) page of the documentation has a paragraph on things to look out for when substituting for classes.

Once that is sorted there are a few other tweaks to the test required to get it to run. I've commented those parts, and done some minor renames to make it a bit easier for me to follow.

```
[Test]
public void ctor_whenviewbuttonclick_callsviewButtonClickevent()
{
    var view = Substitute.For<IView>();
    var repo = Substitute.For<Repository>();
    //Stub out GivenId
    view.GivenId.Returns("42");
    Student st = new Student();
    //Make GetById return a specific Student for the expected ID
    repo.GetById(42).Returns(x => st);

    StudentPresenter sp = new StudentPresenter(view, repo);

    view.ButonClick += Raise.Event<Action>();

    view.Received().GetStudent(st);
}
```

The first change is to stub out `GivenId`, as the presenter requires that to be a string that is parseable as an integer. The second is to make `GetById` return the expected student (the [When..do](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/callbacks/) syntax in your original example reassigns the `st` variable. It doesn't set a return value).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, exactly i did same as this after asking question. god bless